# nginx with php + AJAX dumping contents of php file to page

Tags: php, ajax, nginx

I'm moving my server from apache to nginx. Part of my site uses AJAX to update some data. The AJAX is setup using jquery like so

```
$('#refreshtext').load('messageupdates');
```

There is no php extension for `messageupdates` because the apache server was setup to drop the file extensions from php. I've setup my nginx server to do the same and the main page loads fine, as do other pages e.g. http://example.com and http://example.com/example. However the AJAX call results in the contents of the AJAX calls file (`messageupdates.php`) simply being printed out to the page rather than actually running the php code.

The nginx setup looks like this,

```
server {
    listen 8000; #Using 8000 as test port while apache is still live

    root /var/www/html/example.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {  
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @extensionless;
    }

location @extensionless {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files  $uri =404;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index  index.php;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~/\.ht {
        deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be some sort of local caching issue which is strange since the site had only been accessed over port 443 (standard https) rather than 8000/8043 the test ports. Clearing the caches and enabled SSL, forcing a different port connection, resolved the issue.